# Android Contact Search only phone book

Tags: android

I need to find contact which saved in my Android phone, But save numbers are repeated in SIM and Google contact, Then That are returning before return Phone contact.

Is there any way to query phone contacts only?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ContactsContract.Contacts class. it will give you all data for contacts only.

Comment: It's not good solution, because if you have same contact in SIM, then this not working, Because It first give SIM contact  instead of Phone contacts.